# Is it still possible to retrieve the user url using the YouTube Data API (v3)

Tags: youtube-api

I've heard that the new YouTube Data API (v3) does not retrieve the user url  anymore? Is that correct?

I am the Product Owner of a Community Software and I would like to enrich the public profile of a user with social network content.

So for example as a Community Member I want to connect my community account with my YouTube Account (google+) so that I can display and share the url of my YouTube account with other community members.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) method, you'll get both [G+ username](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.googlePlusUserId) as well as channel url.